# How to solve the error appeared with submitting array Job?

Tags: arrays, jobs, pbs

I'm a biology student and this is the first experience to run array job on server, so please be patient with me.
I'm trying to submit the PBS script for doing blast task on each input file. My input file names are, file1.fa file2.fa file3.fa file4.fa file5.fa file6.fa. The PBS script is like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N run_x3
#PBS -l ncpus=4
#PBS -l mem=30G
#PBS -l walltime=200:00:00
#PBS -J 1-6
#PBS -o stdout_file
#PBS -e stderr_file

cd /home/mary/software/ncbi-blast-2.2.30+/bin
./blastx -query file_${1 2 3 4 5 6}.fa -db uni_database -out blast_file{1 2 3 4 5 6}.xml -evalue 1e-3 -outfmt 5 -show_gis -num_alignments 15 -num_threads 3
```

I run the job as qsub run_x3.sh. but the following error was appeared:
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1007-1.chpc.SC: line 12: file_${1 2 3 4 5 6}.fa: bad substitution

I would be highly appreciate if you could please help me to solve the problem. Also, it is really kind of you please let me know if something wrong in the PBS file. As I mentioned earlier I have no enough computer knowledge to resolve such issue.

Thank you very much in advance and looking forward to hearing from you.

Best,
Mary

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are intending to do with ${1 2 3 4 5 6} is have that evaluate to the array id that is executing. If so, you can use $PBS_ARRAYID:

```
./blastx -query_file_${PBS_ARRAYID} ...
```

This will give you 1 for job 1, 2 for job 2, etc. Specifically, do not put

```
./blastx file1.fa
```

Write

```
./blastx file${PBS_ARRAY_ID}.fa
```

to make it unique for each job run.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have 6 files named file1.fa file2.fa file3.fa file4.fa file5.fa file6.fa, which the blastx program should be run on them. I wrote ./blastx -query file1.fa file2.fa ....file6.fa {PBS_ARRAY_ID} ... also try ./blastx -query file_{PBS_ARRAY_ID}.fa, which appeared error for both. Could you please write the full command for this part? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks dbeer. I wrote like what you kindly suggested, ./blastx file${PBS_ARRAY_ID}.fa, but the below error was appeared: (Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `file.fa'), what's wrong in your opinion? I'm very grateful for your helpful suggestion to resolve the issue.

Comment: What version of PBS are you using? This variable is defined for Torque. To request an array in Torque, you should have a -t option. I didn't noticed before that you have #PBS -J 1-5. This probably needs to be -t.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt comment. I'm using torque (version of 2.4.16). I also tried the task with -t instead of -J, but the problem still exist. I run the program with the command of qsub -t 1-6 PBS_file.sh, but the same error was appeared that says Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `file.fa', 
Please help me....

Comment: Any suggestion and comments, please